# Pass current cex.lab value to another function; Specify distance between lines of texts

Tags: r, axis-labels

Question 1: Suppose I have a function like the one below, which allows me to plot lines and also print multiple lines of texts below the x-axis (Sorry that it is the simplest code that I could come up with. I am open to any suggestions on how to make it neater!). When there is more than one line of text below the x-axis, it will probably overlap with the x-axis label. So I decided to use mtext() to plot the x-axis label.

```
Sampleplot = function(x, text, xlab = NULL,...){
    if(!is.null(text)){
        text.n=length(text)       #Number of lines of text
        text.n2=length(text[[1]]) #Number of words. Here I am assuming equal number in 
                                  #each list item
        text.n=rep(1:text.n, each=text.n2)
        matplot(x, axes = FALSE,...)
        axis(2)
        axis(1, labels = FALSE,at = 1:text.n2)
        args.mtext=c(mtext, list(text=unlist(text), 
                     line=text.n, at=1:text.n2, side=1))
        mtext(xlab, line=max(text.n+1.5), side=1)
        invisible(do.call(mapply, args.mtext))
    }else matplot(x,...)
 }

 #Dataset and texts
 dataset = cbind(sort(rlnorm(4)),sort(rlnorm(4)),sort(rlnorm(4)))
 texts = list(letters[1:4], 1:4, letters[11:14])

 #Sample plot:
 par(mar=c(10,6,4,2))
 Sampleplot(dataset, texts, xlab = "This is the label for x-axis", 
            type="b", pch=1)
```

[image]

---

Now, suppose I would like to increase the label size:

```
 Sampleplot(dataset, texts, xlab = "This is the label for x-axis", 
            type="b", pch=1, cex.lab=3)
```

Of course, this is not going to do anything for the x axis label since it's created not using matplot() but using mtext().

One possible solution is to make cex.lab an explicit argument in the function, and also add it in matplot

```
Sampleplot2 = function(x, text, xlab = NULL, cex.lab = NULL, ...){      #<- HERE!!
    if(is.null(cex.lab)) cex.lab = 1
    if(!is.null(text)){
        text.n=length(text)       #Number of lines of text
        text.n2=length(text[[1]]) #Number of words. Here I am assuming equal number in 
                                  #each list item
        text.n=rep(1:text.n, each=text.n2)
        matplot(x, axes = FALSE, cex.lab=cex.lab,...)                #<- HERE!
        axis(2)
        axis(1, labels = FALSE,at = 1:text.n2)
        args.mtext=c(mtext, list(text=unlist(text), 
                     line=text.n, at=1:text.n2, side=1))
        mtext(xlab, line=max(text.n+1.5), side=1, cex=cex.lab)   #<- HERE!
        invisible(do.call(mapply, args.mtext))
    }else matplot(x,...)
 }

 par(mar=c(10,6,4,2))
 Sampleplot2(dataset, texts, xlab = "This is the label for x-axis", 
            type="b", pch=1, cex.lab=2)
```

[image: I accidentally recreated the dataset, so this plot doesn't look like the previous one]

However, this solution seems far from elegant. So I wonder if there is any way to pass the cex.lab value WITHOUT having to explicitly put it in the function definition. I tried to use par()$cex.lab, but unlike par()$mar, which gives you the current margin status, par()$cex.lab only seems to give you the default label size, which is 1.

Question 2: As you can see in my plots, the spacing between the different lines of texts is kind of wide. I wonder if there is any way I can measure the height of the text, and I can use the height to perhaps decide how wide the space should be between different lines of texts.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: If your only concern is overlapping the x-label, why not use `par` to adjust the margins of your plot region, thus giving you more room to write your lines of text?  BTW,  `par()$name` gives you the current value of said parameter. If you set `par(cex.lab)<-34.5` that value will remain until you clear it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I considered using just mar=. But I have yet to figure out the relationship between the amount of margin required and the size of font below the x-axis. I am trying to make this code part of a routine I do. So instead of checking how wide the bottom margin has to be, I would like the script to be able to determine it based on the number of lines of text and font size of the text, as well as the x-axis label size. Also, regarding par()$name, I got NULL when I used it. Mmm..

Comment: Would `?strheight`be helpful to determine how much space your text takes up?  See this question from the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10490763/496803