# a plot in R coming out of the margins?

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot in R and for some reason, when I enlarge the axis font, the plot window does not become larger as well. This makes the text of the axis be cut. Any ideas how to fix that?

I am talking about the Y axis here.

I am using R on Mac OS X.

Comment: This similar question may be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490763/automatic-adjustment-of-margins-in-horizontal-bar-chart/10490953

Comment: Why don't you provide a reproducible example?